# Regexp for slightly different strings in javascript if condition

Tags: javascript, regex

So i am getting in loop with this problem, that should be relatively easy, the problem is that i have slightly different strings that came from Database:

> Honda VIP..., Honda LL Ultra..., Honda LL..., Honda LL start 5000i, Honda LL ultra 5000i

where i present image1.svg if the string that comes is (Honda VIP..., Honda LL Ultra..., Honda LL...)
or i present image2.svg is the image tha comes is exactly (Honda LL start 5000i, Honda LL ultra 5000i)

my code is:

```
...

else if (panel.match(/Honda VIP|Honda LL Ultra|Honda LL/i)) {
   return 'asset/image1.svg';
else if (panel.match(/Honda LL start 5000i|Honda LL ultra 5000i/i))
   return 'asset/image2.svg';
```

but the return is always image1, because if falls in "Honda LL" or "Honda LL ultra". i've tried to use \s+ into white spaces of the second else if:

```
panel.match(/Honda LL\s+start\s+5000i|Honda LL\s+ultra\s+5000i/i)
```

but no results.

Can someone help me on that?

Comment: Is this because they're always matching the final `Honda LL` in the first regex? If that's the case, try swapping the conditions.

Comment: That is not Java code! Did you mean JavaScript?

Comment: omg sorry.. my fault

Comment: i tried swaping the conditions but no effect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Whatever this language is*, it looks like the `Honda LL` at the end of the first regex is matching everything that the second regex would match.

Swap the conditions, so that the more-specific patterns would be matched first:

```
else if (panel.match(/Honda LL start 5000i|Honda LL ultra 5000i/i))
   return 'asset/image2.svg';
else if (panel.match(/Honda VIP|Honda LL Ultra|Honda LL/i)) {
   return 'asset/image1.svg';
```

Comment: Or make it an exact match: `panel.match(/^(Honda VIP|Honda LL Ultra|Honda LL)$/i)`

Comment: @Andreas or stop using regex, and use, say, a switch (a little harder to do case insensitively, though).

Comment: uhmm i see that "Honda LL" is getting all the conditions, because it falls there..  but  can i search for some string that contais/ends with  start 5000i or ultra 5000i and then falls into image2?

Comment: @Andy Turne i cannot change the base code.. theres a lot of else if conditions there.. ( but with differente other makes.. )

Comment: @Bruno if you can't change the code then I'm not sure what you're hoping you can do.

Comment: Andy, i can't change the else if conditions. Just the regex expressions to catch what i want. thank you for your help! it worked

Answer (score 1):

By the way, can we have a regexp to start with some exactly string and then have variations in front? I was trying

```
} else if (panel.match(/^(Honda|.*B16|B18|B20|Vtec)$/i)) {
          return 'image.svg';
```

Like i want to catch the string that starts with Honda something B16 or Honda B16, or Honda B18 and so on at that list.. my code doesn't even get hit. but shouldn't the /^ /$ be working and catching the first string and then check the others?

I tried

```
} else if (panel.match(/^(Honda)$.*B16|B18|B20|Vtec/i)) {
          return 'image.svg';
```

but if i hit like 'CRX B16' it gets hited, but it shouldn't because it doesn't start with Honda...